# os.path.getmtime when file doesn't exist

Tags: python, os.path

How do I set a variable to None or null when the file doesn't exist
for example:

```
lastModified = os.path.getmtime("/xyz.csv") if os.path.getmtime("/xyz.csv") is not None else null
```

So I would like `lastModified` variable to be the time the file was last modified when the file exists else to be null when it doesn't exist.

Any

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *exists* function from *os.path* module:

```py
from os.path import getmtime, exists

file_path = './file.txt'
last_mod = getmtime(file_path) if exists(file_path) else None
print(last_mod)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from os.path import exists

file_exists = exists(path_to_file)
if file_exists:
    lastModified = os.path.getmtime("/xyz.csv")
else:
    lastModified = None
```